# devart oracle 9.3- entity framework 7 ( or core 1) Mapping can't recognize decimal at visual studio 2017

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, mapping, decimal, devart

I am working on a .Net Core class library project.I use Devart entity framework core to connect oracle database. I use devart's oracle mapping methods at link
 http://blog.devart.com/entity-framework-core-1-entity-framework-7-support.html

I can get datas successfully when type of columns of table is string. But, if type of columns of table is decimal, complier gives me error below:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0452  The type 'decimal?' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'OraclePropertyBuilderExtensions.ForOracleHasColumnName<TEntity>(PropertyBuilder<TEntity>, string)'.
```

my mapping function is:

```
 private void MyTableMapping(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>().ForOracleToTable(@"MyTable");
            modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>().Property<string>(x => x.SIRKETID).ForOracleHasColumnName(@"SIRKET_ID").ForOracleHasColumnType(@"VARCHAR2").ValueGeneratedNever().HasMaxLength(2);//this  line is ok
            modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>().Property<decimal>(x => x.ID).ForOracleHasColumnName(@"ID").ForOracleHasColumnType(@"NUMBER").IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();//this  line gives error
         }
```

Sorry for my low English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your report. We have reproduced the issue and will notify you when it is fixed.

As a workaround, please use:

```
optionsBuilder.UseOracle("oracle_connection_string");
modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>().Property<decimal>(x => x.ID).HasColumnName(@"ID").HasColumnType(@"NUMBER").IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

Comment: The bug with using the ForOracleHasColumnName and ForOracleHasColumnType modelBuilder methods with the value-type properties in EF Core is fixed: http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=35436.

Comment: Thanks for your
interests